# Placement of “this morning” in a sentence with a noun clause

Tags: word-order

There are two sentences. They need to be combined. The second one should be the noun clause. However, I do not know how should I place the phrase "this morning" in the sentence. What is the rule for this?

Sentences:

> The doctor ordered this morning.
>   His patient is released before noon

Actually, my main concern is whether I can place this morning between ordered and this morning as in 1. sentence. I thought it would seem like "that" modifies the morning in that case.

Comment: What did the doctor order?

Comment: You have three choices: _This morning the doctor ordered that ..._; _The doctor ordered this morning that..._; _The doctor this morning ordered that ..._. All of them are possible, depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

There is no set rule, but there are stylistic differences.

Your sentence may be formulated as either

> The doctor ordered *this morning* *that* his patient *be* released before noon.
>   *This morning*, the doctor ordered his patient *be* released before noon.
>   The doctor *this morning* ordered his patient be released before noon.
>   The doctor ordered his patient be released *this morning* before noon.
>   The doctor ordered his patient *be* released before noon *this morning*.
>
> The doctor ordered his patient *to be* released before noon *this morning*.

all have the same meaning.

Comment: I basically agree with this. The trick is of course using be released.

Comment: The third one is very poor construction.

Comment: You omitted "The doctor this morning ordered that ..."

Comment: Those actually don't all have the same meaning. In the first 3, _this morning_ refers to when the doctor gave the order. In the last 2, _this morning_ attaches to _before noon_, describing when the patient is to be released, saying nothing about when the doctor gave the order. Or at least they could mean that.

Comment: You omitted versions including the explicit infinitive marker in "subjunctive" constructions: *...ordered the patient **to** be released...,* which I suspect would probably be the more common phrasing today (particularly in *conversational* contexts).